# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, typeerror

I'm getting this error message in the console for my background changer Chrome extension. What am I doing wrong? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Code is listed below.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
at injectCSS (popup.js:26)
at HTMLInputElement. (popup.js:8)

```
const colorEl = document.getElementById('color-changer');

const rotateEl = document.getElementById('rotate');

const rotate3DEl = document.getElementById('rotate3d');

colorEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
  injectCSS(`body {
    background-color: ${colorEl.value}!important;
   }`);
});

rotateEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
  injectCSS(`body {
      transform: rotate(${rotateEl.value}deg)!important;
  }`);
});

rotate3DEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
  injectCSS(`body {
        transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,${rotate3DEl.value}deg)!important;
    }`);
});

   function injectCSS(css) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, ([tab]) => {
    if (!tab) return;
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
       css,
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
    });
  });
```

}

Comment: Sounds like your popup.js is a content script. It can't use chrome.tabs or chrome.scripting API. Do it in the background script in an onMessage listener, for example.